# Questionnaire validity with imputed data, possible?

Tags: survey, data-imputation, validity

I would like to validate a 30-item questionnaire. There is a a lot of missing data. How do I handle missing data.

My questions are the following:

a) Do I have to use only complete case data to validate the questionnaire?

b) Can I use Multiple Imputation to perform a Confirmatory Factor analysis?

c) If yes to b) Can you give me an explanation how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Miherz. These look like three different questions (i.e. I suggest you pose them separately).